# How to pass if value for date is NULL in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, date, nullable

Why this happen, after I save the null date, the date become `01/01/1900`

**expected**: if there have no any data inside date field, then it should be null inside database.

Below was my code. Please help me to fix it. Thanks in advance

```
.AddWithValue("@issuedDate", FormatDate(psIssuedDate.Trim, 
                BTW_Constant.kiDateTimeFormat_01))
```

Comment: Not an answer, but if you're making extensive use of `AddWithValue`, [you might want to read this](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: What does `FormatDate` return if the date is null?  Is your column in the database set to allow null values?  Does it have a default value set?

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes, in the database date is allow null values..

Comment: @JamesThorpe `FormatDate` become as `01/01/1900`

Comment: So your issue is in that function - I don't believe it's a standard function, can you post it?

Comment: You'll need to 2 things, `FormatDate` return type should be `Date?` or `Nullable(Of Date)` and your db column should allow nulls.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim iDate as Nullable(Of Date) = psIssuedDate.Trim
Dim DateStr as String   ' output Date string

If IsDbNull(iDate) Then
   DateStr = "NULL"
Else
   DateStr = FormatDate(iDate, BTW_Constant.kiDateTimeFormat_01))
End If

.AddWithValue("@issuedDate", DateStr)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell you're assuming the return value of `FormatDate` is a string and assigning that from a string. The OP was facing an issue in saving NULL to the database not on reading it back. NULLs are saving as `01/01/1900` based on that first post.

Comment: No, it is not assigned from a string, but from a nullable date. The problem is, that FormatDate returns 1900/01/01 if the date is NULL (though original input looks like a string - it might also need some casting, but I consider it off topic). If you pass a DateStr string which is either a formatted date or NULL (for a null date value), you get over this problem. The first part might be simplified, depending on the way he gets the date, but it unimportant for this proposed solution.

Comment: In your code, what is `psIssuedDate`?  Is it a `String` or is it a `DateTime`?  If it is a `DateTime` then you cannot call `Trim` on it.   If it is a `String`, then you cannot assign it to an instance of `Nullable(Of DateTime)`.  Using strings when `DateTimes` are needed is unnecessary and should be discouraged.  Use `DateTime` variables when the data type in the database is `DateTime`.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I have no idea where he gets psIssuedDate and a good solution depends on it. Perhaps he converted Date into string in the first place...

Comment: @ChrisDunaway that's my concern above. Trimming `paIssuedDate` then assigning that to a `Date?` shouldn't be possible. And then assigning a string to the `@issuedDate` parameter is something I would discourage. It's best to save a date as a date and format it if need be at run time. To quote OP; "expected: if there have no any data inside date field, then it should be null inside database." This solution attempts to handle null as a string literal as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I just change inside my SQL statement, and it work well. SQL statement as below:

```
INSERT INTO ClientBankGuarantee ([issuedDate]) VALUES (CAST(NULLIF (@issuedDate, '') AS DATETIME))
```

And for code behind as below:

```
 If .Item("IssuedDate") Is DBNull.Value Then
         txtIssuedDate.Text = String.Empty
 Else
         txtIssuedDate.Text = CType(FormatString(.Item("IssuedDate")).Trim, Date)
 End If
```

Thanks again for those share a lot of information and tips to me.